# Cannot resolve class soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Class referenced in the layout file, soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView, was not found in the project or the libraries.

build.gradle (Module) >>>
`implementation 'com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.3.0'`

build.gradle (Project) >>>
`maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

XML >>>

```
    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:neumorph_backgroundColor="@color/bg"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="@color/dark_shadow"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="@color/light_shadow"
        app:neumorph_shapeAppearance="@style/Card">

       
    </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>
```

Comment: can you please share your gradle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines in build.gradle project level file below buildscript

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```